# How to do a responsive Image over heading layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I m trying to do a responsive page using bootstrap latest. My page layout looks like this :

[image]

as you can see the image at the back and the heading text with **"Selling ...."** are overlapeed but when u resize it doent keept its responsive and it mess up , please help.

my css:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> | Home </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href=<?php echo base_url()."assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";?> rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=<?php echo base_url()."assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css";?> rel="stylesheet"
```

Comment: what media queries have you written for the responsive behaviour?

Comment: added snippe tof my css

Comment: chk if any hardcoded inline stylesheet for the div or images?

Answer (score 1):

Without media queries the best way to ensure that the image scales is to use `width: 100%; height: auto;` which will force its width to the size of its container. An alternative is to wrap the image in a `div` container and then make the `div` responsive with an `overflow: hidden` to chop off any part of the image that spills out. This is pretty hacky though.

Otherwise use media queries for specific breakpoints. This is pretty much the only way to do it if you're wanting to control exactly what part of the image the user sees at specific sizes.

We can give more helpful advice if we can see the specific CSS for the image as well as how it's getting messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the class of the image to img-responsive?

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

Comment: i have used it as background image of the div element